# Combining derivatives of a composition of function

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-spaces

I was studying the proof of a proposition, which states the closure of tangent spaces under addition and scalar multiplication. The proof is straightforward for the most part, however, I can't seem to understand this application of differentiation across the composed functions. What follows is the complete proof.

> Proof. Let $(U, x)$ be a chart on $M,$ with $U$ a neighbourhood of $p$.
> i) Define the curve
> $$
> \sigma(t):=x^{-1}((x \circ \gamma)(t)+(x \circ \delta)(t)-x(p))
> $$
> Note that $\sigma$ is smooth since it is constructed via addition and composition of smooth maps and, moreover:
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \sigma(0) &=x^{-1}(x(\gamma(0))+x(\delta(0))-x(p)) \\
> &\left.=x^{-1}(x(p))+x(p)-x(p)\right) \\
> =x^{-1}(x(p)) \\
> &=p
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> Thus $\sigma$ is a smooth curve through $p$. Let $f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(U)$ be arbitrary. Then we have
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> X_{\sigma, p}(f) &:=(f \circ \sigma)^{\prime}(0) \\
> &=\left[f \circ x^{-1} \circ((x \circ \gamma)+(x \circ \delta)-x(p))\right]^{\prime}(0)
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> where $\left(f \circ x^{-1}\right): \mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $((x \circ \gamma)+(x \circ \delta)-x(p)): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d},$ so by the multivariable
> chain rule
> $$
> =\left[\partial_{a}\left(f \circ x^{-1}\right)(x(p))\right]\left(\left(x^{a} \circ \gamma\right)+\left(x^{a} \circ \delta\right)-x^{a}(p)\right)^{\prime}(0)
> $$
> $=\left[\partial_{a}\left(f \circ x^{-1}\right)(x(p))\right]\left(\left(x^{a} \circ \gamma\right)^{\prime}(0)+\left(x^{a} \circ \delta\right)^{\prime}(0)\right)$
> $=\left(f \circ x^{-1} \circ x \circ \gamma\right)^{\prime}(0)+\left(f \circ x^{-1} \circ x \circ \delta\right)^{\prime}(0)$
> $=(f \circ \gamma)^{\prime}(0)+(f \circ \delta)^{\prime}(0)$
> $=:\left(X_{\gamma, p} \oplus X_{\delta, p}\right)(f)$

Here lies my doubt: how does the third step follow from the second?

> $$
> =\left[\partial_{a}\left(f \circ x^{-1}\right)(x(p))\right]\left(\left(x^{a} \circ \gamma\right)+\left(x^{a} \circ \delta\right)-x^{a}(p)\right)^{\prime}(0)
> $$
> $=\left[\partial_{a}\left(f \circ x^{-1}\right)(x(p))\right]\left(\left(x^{a} \circ \gamma\right)^{\prime}(0)+\left(x^{a} \circ \delta\right)^{\prime}(0)\right)$
> $=\left(f \circ x^{-1} \circ x \circ \gamma\right)^{\prime}(0)+\left(f \circ x^{-1} \circ x \circ \delta\right)^{\prime}(0)$
> $=(f \circ \gamma)^{\prime}(0)+(f \circ \delta)^{\prime}(0)$
> $=:\left(X_{\gamma, p} \oplus X_{\delta, p}\right)(f)$

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nchF1fRGSY3R3rP1QmjUg7fe28tAS428/view)'s a link to the original notes.
It comes in Chapter 9, Proposition 9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what point you mean by "third step", but: the multivariable chain rule says that if $h:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ and $k:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R^d}$, then the derivative of $h\circ k:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ at $0\in\mathbb{R}$ is given by
$$
(h\circ k)'(0) = Dh(k(0))\cdot Dk(0) = \partial_ah(k(0))\, (k^a)'(0).
$$
Now apply this with $h = f\circ x^{-1}$ and $k = x\circ \gamma + x\circ\delta - x(p)$ or $k=x\circ \gamma + x\circ\delta$ (depending on which step you mean).

Comment: So sorry, I was referring to the line just before the end of the proof. The line where the partial of the function h, composes with the derivative of the function k taken at 0.
I understood the application of the chain rule, but I don't understand how the composition of both functions in that line is a valid move, because the two derivatives are to be scalar multiplied.

Comment: I still don't really understand exactly what you mean (e.g., what do you mean by "the two derivatives are to be scalar multiplied"?). But this step is just using the fact that $(f\circ x^{-1})\circ(x\circ\gamma+x\circ\delta) = (f\circ x^{-1})\circ (x\circ\gamma) + (f\circ x^{-1})\circ(x\circ\delta)$, and the fact that the derivative of the sum is the sum of the derivatives.

Comment: I believe that it is:
$$
\left(f \circ x^{-1}\right)\cdot (x \circ \gamma+x \circ \delta)
$$
where the dot is scalar multiplication, and not the composition 
$$
\left(f \circ x^{-1}\right)\circ (x \circ \gamma+x \circ \delta)
$$
So, I don't see how one could arrive at this result
$$
\left(f \circ x^{-1}\right) \circ(x \circ \gamma+x \circ \delta)=\left(f \circ x^{-1}\right) \circ(x \circ \gamma)+\left(f \circ x^{-1}\right) \circ(x \circ \delta)
$$

Comment: Huh? What is the "it" you're referring to here? You need calculate the derivative of the second expression (with composition), not the first (with scalar multiplication). As for why the last statement is true, it's by definition of what is meant by the sum of two functions. Just apply both sides to an arbitrary $t\in \mathbb{R}$ - they give the same thing.

Comment: Ah, I see. The derivative to be calculated is the second expression, and on arriving at the expression
$$
\left[\partial_{a}\left(f \circ x^{-1}\right)(x(p))\right]\left(\left(x^{a} \circ \gamma\right)^{\prime}(0)+\left(x^{a} \circ \delta\right)^{\prime}(0)\right)
$$
since the point $x^{a}(p)$ became zero, one can simply identify the expression with 
$$
\left[f \circ x^{-1} \circ((x \circ \gamma)+(x \circ \delta))\right]^{\prime}(0)
$$
and that leads to
$$
\left(f \circ x^{-1} \circ x \circ \gamma\right)^{\prime}(0)+\left(f \circ x^{-1} \circ x \circ \delta\right)^{\prime}(0)
$$